# Splitting character string at a particular character and preserving that character

Tags: r, dplyr, character

I have found answers for this for other languages but not R so I apologize if this is a duplicate.

I am using the `separate()` function in R and am curious if it is possible to split a column into two columns whenever a certain character appears. For example:

```
data

    ID          Value
0011ER00      91346
0011ER46      59961
0011ER4610    53968
0011ER4620    55083
0011ER4630    51112
0011ER4640    67480
0011ER4650    45612
0011ER4660    53968
```

And I would like to split the ID column so that the data looks like this:

```
data

Code    Region  Value
0011    ER00    91346
0011    ER46    59961
0011    ER4610  53968
0011    ER4620  55083
0011    ER4630  51112
0011    ER4640  67480
0011    ER4650  45612
0011    ER4660  53968
```

I tried the code:

```
data %>% 
  separate(ID, into = c("Code", "Region"), sep = "E")
```

but then I am not able to preserve the E in the result and get:

```
Code    Region  Value
0011    ER00    91346
0011    R46     59961
0011    R4610   53968
0011    R4620   55083
0011    R4630   51112
0011    R4640   67480
0011    R4650   45612
0011    R4660   53968
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `extract` from `tidyr`. The `regex` argument matches the capture groups (in parentheses) and separate them into the variables specified in the `into` argument. Note that the number of capture groups must equal the number of `into` variable names:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  extract(ID, c("Code", "Region"), regex = "(^\\d+)([[:alpha:]]+\\d+)")
```

**Output:**

```
  Code Region Value
1 0011   ER00 91346
2 0011   ER46 59961
3 0011 ER4610 53968
4 0011 ER4620 55083
5 0011 ER4630 51112
6 0011 ER4640 67480
7 0011 ER4650 45612
8 0011 ER4660 53968
```

**Data:**

```
data <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:8, .Label = c("0011ER00", "0011ER46", 
"0011ER4610", "0011ER4620", "0011ER4630", "0011ER4640", "0011ER4650", 
"0011ER4660"), class = "factor"), Value = c(91346L, 59961L, 53968L, 
55083L, 51112L, 67480L, 45612L, 53968L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

### `extract` vs `separate`:

In contrast to using `separate` (in @akrun's answer), `extract` matches specifically the contents of your output variables, while `separate` matches the splitting character (or a zero-length position in the case of lookarounds). Both are valid and have their pros and cons.

Depending on your use case, `separate` is generally more useful if you want to split your variable into multiple columns based on some delimiter, without needing to know what the contents of your output variables should be.

`extract` is more useful when you have to be sure that you are grabbing the correct characters from your input for each output variable.

In OP's case it doesn't really matter since he/she is only splitting the input into two variables with one "delimiter" and the concatenation of the output exactly matches the input.

Comment: This worked, but im curious as to the difference between extract and separate and if there is any avantage to using one over the other.

Comment: @quantumofnolace Adding a note at the end of my answer to address your question.

Answer (score 3):

An option would be to a regex lookaround to split at the junction between a digit and character. Here, we are also making it more generalizable by splitting at the junction of any digit followed by letter 'E'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
   separate(ID, into = c("Code", "Region"), sep = "(?<=[0-9])(?=E)")
#  Code Region Value
#1 0011   ER00 91346
#2 0011   ER46 59961
#3 0011 ER4610 53968
#4 0011 ER4620 55083
#5 0011 ER4630 51112
#6 0011 ER4640 67480
#7 0011 ER4650 45612
#8 0011 ER4660 53968
```

---

Or another option is to insert a delimiter before the `,` with `str_replace` and then do the `separate`

```
data %>%
   mutate(ID = str_replace(ID, "E", ",E")) %>% 
   separate(ID, into = c("Code", "Region"))
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c("0011ER00", "0011ER46", "0011ER4610", "0011ER4620", 
"0011ER4630", "0011ER4640", "0011ER4650", "0011ER4660"), Value = c(91346L, 
59961L, 53968L, 55083L, 51112L, 67480L, 45612L, 53968L)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: @avid_useR my initial answer was `(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])` more generalizable until I saw your answer which specifically used `ER` and then I checked OP's post which also showed the specific character.  Also, note that I didn't start comparing your answer until I find you that you are doing some kind of a comparson

Comment: @avid_useR  it's okay. I removed thee comparison part from my answer.  Thanks for clarification

Comment: Yea, +1 to your answer, and feel free to add any pros and cons you can think of.